# Analytic function symmetric wrt inversion: $f(z^{-1}) = f(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose $f$ is analytic on ${\mathbb C}\setminus \{0\}$ and satisfies $f(z^{-1}) = f(z)$ for all nonzero $z$.  Show that there exists an entire analytic function $g$ such that $f(z) = g(z + \frac{1}{z})$ for all nonzero $z$.

I thought maybe using either Cauchy's formula or Laurent series but I don't see why a Laurent series $\sum_{n \in {\mathbb Z}} a_n z^n$ necessarily has $a_n = a_{-n}$ or why it must converge.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean $f(z)=g(z)+g(1/z)$?

Answer (score 1):

Expand $f$ in a Laurent series with coefficients $a_n$ about $0$. The condition shows that $a_n=a_{-n}$.

Now use the fact that $a_n(z^n+1/z^n)$ can be written as a sum of powers of $(z+1/z)$.

For example,
$$(z+1/z)^2=2+(z^2+1/z^2),$$
$$(z+1/z)^3=3(z+1/z)+(z^3+1/z^3),$$
and so on.

Comment: Why does this imply $f(z)=g(z+1/z)$?

Comment: Are you sure? This gives $f(z) = g(z)+g(1/z)$, not $g(z+1/z)$.

Comment: @martycohen You're both right, but luckily it's fixable.